# Creating PDF from a single JPG file using Ghostscript - image placement issue inside PDF

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I'm trying to output a PDF file from a JPG file using Ghostscript. The following command works fine:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -o /pdf_from_image.pdf /path/to/viewjpeg.ps -c \(/source_image.jpg\) viewJPEG
```

Based on existing threads and Ghostscript documentation I'm using `-sPAPERSIZE=a4` to generate the output in A4 format. The PDF generates fine, but the PROBLEM is when the image dimensions don't match that of A4, GS puts the image at the bottom of the page with best "width" fit. I think it actually tries to put it in the lower left bottom. To add to it, at times the image is auto rotated.

My question is:
1) Is there any option to put the image on top left corner of the page.
2) Stop GS auto rotating the image.

Any help to put me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PDF and PostScript use a coordinate system with the origin (0,0) in the lower left corner, so Ghostscript is actually doing the 'correct' thing: putting the image at the origin. To place the image at the top, you'd have to subtract the image height from the page height and translate the image upwards by that amount.

As for why some images are being rotated, I can't say for sure. Some JPGs contain metadata that indicates the intended orientation of the image--however, not all software gets the value right. I don't know if Ghostscript respects that metadata, but you could check if your 'bad' images have the correct orientation tag (you can use Exif or similar to inspect them).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know how I may do the translation using Ghostscript. That is what I basically want to do, translate it so that it sits on the top left corner of the page.

Comment: You'll need to learn PostScript, and modify the viewjpeg.ps PostScript program.